# Как результаты парсинга API в формате JSON записать в CSV отдельными строками

Tags: python, json, csv

Задача - сформировать таблицу с данными в формате CSV парсингом API.

В результате парсинга API кодом Python в переменную data получаю такую строку JSON:

```
{
'Identifier': 'edf627bda4f345c5948396e1497a7e48',  
'User': 'USER',  
'State': 'OK',  
'Vin': 'XW8ZZZ61ZJG000000',  
'Count': '2',  
'VehicleType': 'PC',  
'VehicleTypeNumber': '23',  
'Brand': 'VOLKSWAGEN',  
'Model': 'POLO',  
'Year': '2018',  
'Power': '90',  
'TaxiInformations': {'1': {'inn': '7720000000', 
                           'company': 'ООО «Ромашка»', 
                           'date': '22.11.2018'}, 
                     '2': {'inn': '7720000000', 
                           'company': 'ООО «Ромашка»', 
                           'date': '09.12.2020'}
                    },  
'LeasingDetails': {}
}
```

Когда дальше пытаюсь записать результат циклом в файл CSV, то либо все данные добавляются в одну строку, либо в разные строки, но разбитые на отдельные знаки в отдельных столбцах.

Ниже пример кода с двумя вариантами, которые не решают мою задачу:

```
df = pd.read_excel("base_vin.xlsx", header=None, index_col=None)
vin = df.to_numpy().flatten()
password = 'PASSWORD'
data = []

for i in vin:

    url = 'http://site.com/api/searchvinextended?user=USER&password=' + password + '&vin=' + i
    data = requests.get(url).json()

    file = open('result.csv', 'a')
    
    # Вариант 1:
    file.write(json.dumps(data, ensure_ascii=False))

    # Вариант 2
    # writer = csv.writer(file)
    # writer.writerows([json.dumps(data, ensure_ascii=False)])
```

Мне нужно записать данные, указанные через разделитель ',' в отдельные столбцы.
В идеале вообще получить из первой строки JSON заголовки и данные для первой строки, а из остальных писать в последующие строки только данные.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как нужно доработать код?

Comment: а как Вы хотите хранить вложенные объекты (`TaxiInformations`) ? Просто строкой?

Comment: @asanisimov в простом варианте да, строкой, а в сложном варианте (с заголовками) путём объединения заголовков - 'TaxiInformations_1_inn', 'TaxiInformations_1_company' и т.д.

Comment: Вы, думаю, понимаете что сложный реализуем только если у Вас какое то конечное известное кол-во вложенных объектов

Answer (score 1):

Вы же выше по коду используете библиотеку `Pandas`, почему бы и тут не использовать её же?

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
'Identifier': 'edf627bda4f345c5948396e1497a7e48',  
'User': 'USER',  
'State': 'OK',  
'Vin': 'XW8ZZZ61ZJG000000',  
'Count': '2',  
'VehicleType': 'PC',  
'VehicleTypeNumber': '23',  
'Brand': 'VOLKSWAGEN',  
'Model': 'POLO',  
'Year': '2018',  
'Power': '90',  
'TaxiInformations': {'1': {'inn': '7720000000', 
                           'company': 'ООО «Ромашка»', 
                           'date': '22.11.2018'}, 
                     '2': {'inn': '7720000000', 
                           'company': 'ООО «Ромашка»', 
                           'date': '09.12.2020'}
                    },  
'LeasingDetails': {}
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.to_csv('result.csv', index=False)
```

Содержимое `result.csv`:

```
Identifier,User,State,Vin,Count,VehicleType,VehicleTypeNumber,Brand,Model,Year,Power,TaxiInformations,LeasingDetails
edf627bda4f345c5948396e1497a7e48,USER,OK,XW8ZZZ61ZJG000000,2,PC,23,VOLKSWAGEN,POLO,2018,90,"{'inn': '7720000000', 'company': 'ООО «Ромашка»', 'date': '22.11.2018'}",
edf627bda4f345c5948396e1497a7e48,USER,OK,XW8ZZZ61ZJG000000,2,PC,23,VOLKSWAGEN,POLO,2018,90,"{'inn': '7720000000', 'company': 'ООО «Ромашка»', 'date': '09.12.2020'}",
```